# Facebook C# SDK V 5.0.3 Error

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk

I.m trying to implement ASP.NET Application in VB using the Sample example from Facebook C# SDK V 5.0.3 downloads but I got the below error at auth.Autherize(). What's wrong with it?

Precondition failed: !String.IsNullOrEmpty(pathAndQuery)

```
 Dim auth = New CanvasAuthorizer With {.Perms = "user_about_me"}

    If (auth.Authorize()) Then
        ShowFacebookContent()
    End If
```

Answer (score 0):

That is a bug that was fixed a long time ago. You are using a very old version of the Facebook C# SDK. I would recommend upgraded to V6 or at minimum the latest version of V5.